# The code fails at 51st input, test case 2. What could be the problem?

Tags: c++

There is this problem on codeforces, [double ended strings](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1506/C). I have written a code for it which works according to me for all test cases I throw at it. But, I get a wrong answer on test case 2 upon submission. The test case contains 100 inputs and after 51st input my code outputs a single value (8 in my case). It seems the 51st input somehow messes with the code and code doesn't output correct answer for the further inputs. I am not able to see what the 51st input is, as the codeforces shows only few of the input from of the beginning (49 inputs in my case). The code works absolutely fine for those inputs but fails after 51st input.

I know it's lot to ask here on stack overflow, but I am a beginner and can't figure out what's going on.

I have the added the code below with proper comments. Please someone take the efforts to look through it. Thanks in advance.

```
//This code reads input from 'input.txt' file and
//writes output to 'output.txt' file.


#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string>
#define ll long long
#define ld long double
#define mod(x,y) (x>y ? x-y : y-x)
#define sq(x) (x*x)
using namespace std;


//This function finds all possible substrings and stores them in memo.
set<string> memo;
void recurse(string s) {    
    if(memo.find(s) != memo.end() or s.size() == 0) return;
    recurse(s.substr(1,s.size()-1));
    memo.insert(s);
    recurse(s.substr(0,s.size()-1));
}

int solve(string a, string b) {
    string temp;
    int an = a.size(), bn = b.size();

    //Obtain all possible substrings for string with less length.
    if(an>bn) {         
        recurse(b);
        temp = a;
    }
    else {
        recurse(a);
        temp = b;
    }

    //iterating through the memo to find the a substring
    // of max length which is also the part of other string.
    int MAX=0;
    set<string>::iterator it;   
    for(it=memo.begin();it!=memo.end();it++) {  
        string t = *it;                         
        if(temp.find(t) != string::npos) {
            MAX = max(MAX,(int)(t.size()));
        }
    }
    memo.clear();
    return an + bn - MAX - MAX;
}



int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif


    //handle I/O here...
    int T;
    string a,b;
    cin >> T;
    getchar();
    while(T--) {
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << solve(a,b) << "\n";
    }
    //print your result here.
    return 0;
}
```

For I/O, write the input in file named 'input.txt' located in the place where you would save/run this code. You will have your output in file named 'output.txt'.

Comment: I know it's a little bit of a personal gripe for me, but I'd argue that the root problem is that you use a so-called "competition" or "judge" site to learn programming and C++. Which they are *not* supposed to be for. All they teach are really bad habits, many of which are showcased in the code you show. And the don't teach one of the most important parts of programming: ***Debugging***

Comment: I figured out what's causing the problem,
```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
```
After removing this the code got accepted. I don't know why this was causing the problem, I added to it handle I/O operations faster.

Comment: @AdityaHugay *I added to it handle I/O operations faster* -- You should have concentrated on solving the problem first, not concern yourself with "I/O speed".   What if this was an interview for a job?  Would the interviewer be impressed by `sync_with_stdio` calls?  The other thing are those macros such as `ll` -- there is a data type in C++, `int64_t` that describes exactly the type, and you should have used that instead.  There is no need to use a macro that looks like the number `11`.

Comment: I get your point Paul, I guess I was overwhelmed by seeing top coders templates. I have stopped using it in my code and will add when I fully understand how it works.